# Crash in application after updating google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have implemented notifications into my application using Firebase and in the Firebase documentation it suggests that you need to check google play services when using notifications.

I have implemented the check:

```
  public static void checkGooglePlayServices(final Activity activity) {
    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
  }
```

If the google play services is out of date and the user gets the dialog to update it. If the user follows through and updates the google play services then returns back to the application (after the update is complete) and the user goes back to the previous activity i get the crash below:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.app/com.example.app.settings.notifications.NotificationSettingsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is already complete
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3975)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3993)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:178)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1524)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is already complete
   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh.zzTH(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh.setException(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setException(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabj.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabu.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:2434)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1442)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:2951)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:271)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:390)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:209)
   at com.example.app.base.view.BaseActivity.onDestroy(BaseActivity.java:72)
   at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6291)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3962)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3993)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:178)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1524)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Im not sure why i am getting this crash and where to handle it?

Comment: see this thread https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/287 about this issue discussion and its fixed in version 0.5.3

Comment: @Rameshbabu i think there is some confusion i dont think that like u gave me is related to what i am dealing with because i have the lastest version already

Comment: I have the same issue with the 11.0.2 dependency